# Exception while running Android app

Tags: android, exception

I have searched some post for this error but has not found any viable solution for this .

The error is as below 
and my R file is not getting generated

```
? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.mediatek.log2server.EXCEPTION_HAPPEND from system 1340:com.android.phone/1001 pkg com.android.phone
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18770)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:19391)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:501)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2938)
        at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:570)
07-15 21:36:51.738 1357-2571/? E/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler: callback not found for RELEASED message
07-15 21:36:52.200 242-511/? E/MAL-RDS:  (  rds_ru_3gpp_status_ind, 1662) [RDS-E][RU][EVENT_RU_DM_3GPP_STATUS_IND] Invalid u43gpp_status:0x8
07-15 21:36:54.527 904-1028/? E/WifiStateMachine: mIsFullScanOngoing: false, mSendScanResultsBroadcast: false
07-15 21:36:54.537 904-1030/? E/WifiScanningService: WifiSingleScanStateMachine IdleState enter
```

Comment: Hey bud, you can't just post a crash and walk away. You didn't even ask a question. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and at least 1) ask an actual question 2) explain what you're doing that leads to this crash. Help us help you.